# Unable to Get Mouse Button Release Events Android NDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I'm trying to get mouse button events in Android NDK and Native Activity App

But it doesn't seem to detect the mouse button release event!

When I press any button `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_DOWN` part works
But when I release that button `AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_UP` doesn't work

The Android API Level is 30

In the `handle_input_event` callback, I use:

```
// LOGI is just a macro for __android_log_print

int32_t eventType = AInputEvent_getType(event);
int32_t eventAction = AKeyEvent_getAction(event);

switch(eventType)
{
  case AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_MOTION:
  {
    int32_t eventPointerIndex = (eventAction & AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    eventAction &= AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_MASK;

    switch(eventAction)
    {
      case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_DOWN: // This works correctly and prints everything
      {
        int32_t toolType = AMotionEvent_getToolType(event, eventPointerIndex);

        switch (toolType)
        {
          case AMOTION_EVENT_TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE:
          {
            int32_t mouseButton = AMotionEvent_getButtonState(event);

            if (mouseButton & AMOTION_EVENT_BUTTON_PRIMARY)
              LOGI("Left Click Press");
            else if(mouseButton & AMOTION_EVENT_BUTTON_SECONDARY)
              LOGI("Right Click Press");
            else if(mouseButton & AMOTION_EVENT_BUTTON_TERTIARY)
              LOGI("3rd Click Press");

            break;
          }

          case AMOTION_EVENT_TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
          default:
            break;
        }

        break;
      }
      case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_UP: // This doesn't work correctly and prints nothing
      {
        int32_t toolType = AMotionEvent_getToolType(event, eventPointerIndex);

        switch (toolType)
        {
          case AMOTION_EVENT_TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE:
          {
            int32_t mouseButton = AMotionEvent_getButtonState(event);
            LOGI("mouseButton=%d", mouseButton);

            if (mouseButton & AMOTION_EVENT_BUTTON_PRIMARY)
              LOGI("Left Click Release");
            else if(mouseButton & AMOTION_EVENT_BUTTON_SECONDARY)
              LOGI("Right Click Release");
            else if(mouseButton & AMOTION_EVENT_BUTTON_TERTIARY)
              LOGI("3rd Click Release");

            break;
          }
          case AMOTION_EVENT_TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
          default:
            break;
        }

        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is wrong with this?

How do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [AMotionEvent_getAction](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/input#amotionevent_getaction) instead of [AKeyEvent_getAction](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/input#akeyevent_getaction) for [AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_MOTION](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/input#group___input_1ggafa231099d07583c3ed0981e0bb665f55a2182dfda2cceb5425dcc2823b9b6b56a).

```cpp
  eventAction = AMotionEvent_getAction(event)
  // pointer index code here
  switch(eventAction & AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_MASK)
  // cases and stuff
```